# 28x28 mnist image unrolling to concatenate using numpy.vstack. Why is numpy.vstack so slow?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, numpy

I'm trying to do a simple reshape of a 60000,28,28 list of mnist digits into a 60000,784 numpy array where the digits have been unrolled.

To do this the code is this:

```
(xdata,xlabel),(ydata,ylabel)=tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
newxdata=np.array([])
cnt=0
for i in xdata:
 tmpx=i.ravel()
 if cnt == 0:
  newxdata=np.concatenate((newxdata,tmpx))
 else:
  newxdata=np.vstack((newxdata,tmpx))
 cnt=cnt+1
```

Why does this take so long to run? Is there a way to speed it up? Ultimately the data will be fed into a keras model in smaller batches. Would writing a generator that does the loop unrolling when a batchsize is asked for be more performant or would it not make a difference?

Comment: You are looping 60K times, that's why. You must use the available reshape method

Comment: So i thought the concatenation operation would be O(1) in time, but in fact, there's the creation of an array the size of the previous data as a new item gets appended to it, which makes it O(n). I'm not sure what python does for reshape operations, but it is definitely faster

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape a numpy array simply by:

```
newxdata =  xdata.reshape((60000,28*28))
```

for example. Or simply:

```
newxdata =  xdata.reshape((len(xdata),-1))
```

Note that reshape is a numpy function which can used also as:

```
import numpy as np
newxdata =  np.reshape(xdata, (60000,-1))
```

To speed up your loop you could alternatively use libraries like [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) or [CuPy](https://cupy.dev/) or [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I went with that suggestion and had a few additions to the implementation.

Ultimately the newly transformed data would be ingested by a keras function that requires an input of ( batch_size, unrolled image), so i created a generator function .returnbatch(batch_size) that returns a ( batchsize, unrolledimage )